# Python Client Server program gets stucked

Tags: python, client-server

Server Code

```
import socket
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(("192.168.169.10", 9559))
server_socket.listen(5)
import os
import time

client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()
print "Conencted to - ",address,"\n"

while(1):

fp = open('img.jpg','wb+')

start = time.time()
while True:
    strng = client_socket.recv(1024)
    if not strng:
        break
        print 'loop ends'
    fp.write(strng)
fp.close()

print 'total time taken',time.time()-start,'secs'
print "Data Received successfully"

client_socket.send("Hey I am looking for you face")


exit()
```

Client Code

```
import socket,os
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(("192.168.169.10", 9559))

fname = '/home/student/images/andrew1.jpeg'
img = open(fname,'rb')

while True:
strng = img.readline(1024)
if not strng:
    break
client_socket.send(strng)
img.close()

response = client_socket.recv(1024)
print response
exit()
```

The Code gets stucked and when on the client side ctrl +C is pressed the server exits and the client doesnt receive data 
How to achieve two way communication in this scenario ??

Comment: Could you please add more details?  Which line/place does your code get "stuck" in? Are there any errors?

Comment: The server side output :
Got connected to ....
The Client side output is blank , suggests recv() is blocking the client side

Comment: In client side code, why are you using the first `while` loop?

Comment: The while is not required . Even after removing the while loop the program doesnt work . I have modified the program above